# Adding an item: different display in K2

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I have a problem in Youtrader template.
I have created new K2 extra field group, new K2 extra field and new K2 category.
When I'm creating new item, it does not display as sample items.
I want to show extrafields in the right. 
Urls are different also. Different display of items.

I asked at getk2.org, got no answer there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried to upload screenshots, it says that I need at least 10 reputation. Please help me with this problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to show extra fields in each category's item view. Is that enabled?